# Is it possible to execute code after the ServiceProvider is created?

Tags: c#, asp.net, asp.net-core, asp.net-core-3.0, asp.net-core-3.1

I have an ASP.NET Core 3.1 WebApi based project that is written in `C#`. I want to execute code once when the app is finished bootstrapping.

For example, I want to execute the following code once the `IServiceProvider` is created to avoid having to create a second instance of the `IServiceProvider`.

I thought using`.AddOptions()` on the `IServiceCollection` extension will allow me to define a function that will later get called after the `IServiceProvider` is created. But it does not appear to be that way.

Here is what I have done. In the `ConfigureServices(IServiceCollection services)` method I added the following code

```
services.AddOptions()
        .Configure<IServiceProvider>((serviceProvider) =>
        {
            var items = serviceProvider.GetServices<ICustomInterface>();

            foreach (ICustomInterface item in items)
            {
                item.DoSome();
            }
        });
```

However the code inside of `Configure<IServiceProvider>()` never gets called.

How can I call my custom code after the `IServiceProvider` is constructed?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you've seen the source code of [DefaultServiceProviderFactory](https://github.com/aspnet/DependencyInjection/blob/94b9cc9ace032f838e068702cc70ce57cc883bc7/src/DI/DefaultServiceProviderFactory.cs), then yes, you can have your own **ServiceProviderFactory** acts like default and get benefits `to execute code after the ServiceProvider is created`.

ExampleServiceProviderFactory.cs

```cs
public class ExampleServiceProviderFactory : IServiceProviderFactory<IServiceCollection>
{
    private readonly ServiceProviderOptions _options;

    public ExampleServiceProviderFactory(ServiceProviderOptions options)
    {
        if (options == null)
            throw new ArgumentNullException(nameof(options));

        _options = options;
    }

    public IServiceProvider CreateServiceProvider(IServiceCollection containerBuilder)
    {
        var serviceProvider =  containerBuilder.BuildServiceProvider(_options);

        // TODO: here you go
        var items = serviceProvider.GetServices<ICustomInterface>();

        foreach (ICustomInterface item in items)
        {
            item.DoSome();
        }

        return serviceProvider;
    }
}
```

The easier and faster way to use this **ServiceProviderFactory** instead of **DefaultServiceProviderFactory** on statrup would be like this,

Program.cs

```cs
Host.CreateDefaultBuilder(args)
    .UseServiceProviderFactory((context) =>
    {
        var options = new ServiceProviderOptions()
        {
            ValidateOnBuild = false, // default,
            ValidateScopes = context.HostingEnvironment.IsDevelopment(),
        };
        return new CustomServiceProviderFactory(options);
    })
```

Answer (score 0):

Consider your `program.cs` file. Typically you will see `.....Build().Run()` code here to start your web service.

If you split the build and the run phases you can assess the service provider before the service will start serving requests.

```cs
            var host = Host.CreateDefaultBuilder(args)
                .ConfigureWebHostDefaults(webBuilder =>
                {
                    webBuilder.UseStartup<Startup>();
                }).Build();

            // Do your initialization here
            var serviceProvider = host.Services;

            var items = serviceProvider.GetServices<ICustomInterface>();

            foreach (ICustomInterface item in items)
            {
                item.DoSome();
            }

            // Start your service
            host.Run();
```